# JQuery animate scrollTop doesnt work in one page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I cant solve why animate doesnt work only on one page.
Here is Link: https://tachomaster.pl

For test I add little gray sqaure on the left top corner, if you click this, script should scroll you a little down. As you can see it doesnt work only on main page, on any other it works.

Here is testing script:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.test', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: 500
    }, 800);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to hide overflow for all the containers under your body tag

Answer (score 0):

I fix that by changing from

```js
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: 500
}, 800);
```

to

```js
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 500
}, 800);
```

I completly dont know why it works that way and didnt work first way ONLY on main page.